# Is there a parity flag for PowerPC generated directly on ConditionRegister?

Tags: powerpc

On x64 machines there is the [Parity Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_flag) which I want to use related to the result of the last operation (quite like Condition Register (CR) works), however I didn't realize any suitable way of using CR bit masks to get this information.

On [ppc64le ISA](http://openpowerfoundation.org/technical/technical-resources/technical-specifications/) I only found these operations in order to get parity of a register (which could be the result of my operations):

```
The parity of (RS) can be computed as follows.
popcntb RA, RS
prtyd RA, RA
```

However that needs 2 instructions and 1 temporary register. On x64 I get this flag for free after comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the condition register does not reflect parity of the result.  You have to specifically code for this, as you found in the ISA.

My understanding of the x86 parity flag is that it only operates on the least significant byte of the result; you can decide for yourself whether that is useful.  The PowerPC instructions operate either on a word or a doubleword, so if you want to get the parity of the least significant byte, you'll need to ensure the other bytes contain zero, such as with

clrldi Rx,Ry,56